# How to make an Item draggable without flicker when parent's position changes during drag

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to make an item that can be resized by its edges.

For showing a minimal testcase of the problem it is enough to have its left edge draggable, so here it is:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    border.width: 1
    border.color: 'black'
    color: 'red'

    // save original position and size at drag start
    property real origX: 0
    property real origWidth: 0

    // drag this item:
    Item {
        id: dragDummy
        x: 0
        onXChanged: {
            root.x = root.origX + x
            root.width = root.origWidth - x
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: root
        drag.target: dragDummy
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
        drag.onActiveChanged: {
            // onDragStarted -> Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDragStarted" ???
            if(!active) return
            root.origX = root.x
            root.origWidth = root.width
        }
    }
}
```

the problem seems to be that if drag causes parent position to change, that triggers another drag event, causing this flicker:

[image: screenshot]

I'm guessing MouseArea can't help here? Then low level mouse events should be used like in "old-school" apps (i.e. capturing events at root Item, manually compute offset with respect to initial mouse down position, etc...)?

(or I have to move the MouseArea to an ancestor that won't move during drag, which is almost the same...)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice QML Item type called `DragHandler` which people often overlook, but I find that it works very well.

This solution is a little more idiomatic than other suggestions in that it uses a declarative style rather than imperative:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 100
    Item {
        height: 100
        width: handle.x + handle.width / 2
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: handle.x + handle.width / 2
        width: root.width - (handle.x - handle.width/2)
        height: 100
        border{
            width: 1
            color: 'black'
        }
        color: 'red'
    }
    Item {
        id: handle
        x: -width / 2
        width: 50
        height: 100
        DragHandler {
            yAxis.enabled: false
            xAxis{
                minimum: -handle.width
                maximum: root.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I come up with consists of having two `MouseArea`s:

- a `MouseArea` moves with the item to drag, that is used only for hit-testing, so its `onPressed` handler is something like this:

```
    onPressed: (mouse) => {
        mouse.accepted = false
        root.container.myDragTarget = root
    }
    onReleased: root.container.myDragTarget = null
```

- another `MouseArea`, stacked below the others and **not** moving, handles the mouse position change and the dragging:

```
    onPressed: _start = Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY)
    onPositionChanged: {
        if(myDragTarget) {
            var delta = Qt.point(mouseX - _start.x, mouseY - _start.y)
            // do any rounding/snapping of delta here...
            _start.x += delta.x
            _start.y += delta.y
            myDragTarget.x += delta.x
            myDragTarget.y += delta.y
        }
    }
```

This is able to drag the item reliably.

This is also what I wanted to avoid, because it reinvents mouse drag, but in absence of a better solution it is what I am going to use.

I won't accept this answer as I'm curious to see other ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround the movement and new positioning of the dragged `Item` by mapping the coordinates with the [mapToItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method) functions.

In my solution, I've not used the drag functionality of the `MouseArea` as it needs a `drag.target`. I've used the pressed and position changed signals to implement drag behavior. The only downside is the `background` `Item` which is needed for the mapToItem function as it doesn't accept the `Window` due to it not being an `Item`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Shapes

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Item {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            property int rightX
            x: 50
            y: 50
            width: 200
            height: 80
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "black"
            color: "red"

            Rectangle {
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                width: 10
                color: mouseArea.containsMouse || mouseArea.pressed ? "#ff808080" : "#aa808080"

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true

                    onPressed: rectangle.rightX = rectangle.x + rectangle.width

                    onPositionChanged: function(mouse) {
                        if (mouseArea.pressed) {
                            var tmp = mouseArea.mapToItem(background, mouse.x, 0)
                            if (tmp.x <= rectangle.rightX)
                                rectangle.x = tmp.x
                            else
                                rectangle.x = rectangle.rightX

                            rectangle.width = rectangle.rightX - rectangle.x
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```